# Gitlab CI - Run pipeline ONLY when triggered by CRON

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Hello I am new to gitlab, and so far i succeded in doing everything (runners, pipelines, etc...)

But I now want to set automatic tests build only once per day, triggered by a CRON but NOT TRIGGERED by each push made on the git repo.

**I am using a 8.14.2 gitlab without the new SCHEDULE feature**

So I used this gitlab.ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - test

test-karma:
  stage: test
  image: node:8.9.4
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get --yes install npm
    - apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3
  libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1
  libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6
  ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
   - npm install @angular/cli@1.4.5
   - npm install
 environment: dev
 script:
   - ./node_modules/.bin/ng test --single-run=true --watch=false
 only:
   - triggers
 except:
   - pushes
```

But despite the only / except part, the job is triggered :

() For each git push (which i don't want) 
() By the CRON which I want

So I found another way 
1- Set a variable SHOULD_EXECUTE to false on gitlab 
2- Protect every script line by an if statement 
3- Use the following CRON:

```
00 4 * * * curl -X POST -F token=MY_TOKEN -F ref=master -F "variables[SOULD_EXECUTE]=true" http://MY_GITLAB_URL/api/v3/projects/30/trigger/builds
```

4- And changed the gitlab.ci.yml to

```
stages:
  - test

test-karma:
  stage: test
  image: node:8.9.4
  before_script:
    - if [ ${SOULD_EXECUTE} == "true" ]; then apt-get update;fi
    - if [ ${SOULD_EXECUTE} == "true" ]; then apt-get --yes install npm ;fi
    - if [ ${SOULD_EXECUTE} == "true" ]; then apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3
  libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1
  libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6
  ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget;fi
   - if [ ${SOULD_EXECUTE} == "true" ]; then npm install @angular/cli@1.4.5;fi
   - if [ ${SOULD_EXECUTE} == "true" ]; then npm install; else echo "TEST JOB SKIPPED";fi
   - echo 'SOULD_EXECUTE => ' + ${SOULD_EXECUTE}
 environment: dev
 script:
   - if [ ${SOULD_EXECUTE} == "true" ]; then ./node_modules/.bin/ng test --single-run=true --watch=false;fi
 only:
   - triggers
```

It's Ugly... Could some one help me to set this up ? Thank you so much.

regards.

Comment: What happens when you just do `only: - triggers` without the `except: - pushes`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into this. Actually, I added except: pushes because Only trigger wasn't working. However, i had to move repo on gitlab to another group... Since then, it's working like intended. I have no idea why :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue **without knowing how or why**. I had to move the repo to another group in gitlab. And now it's working perfectly, the only : triggers (without except : pushes) enable me to NOT run a pipeline for each pushes, and I can run this with the CRON post call.

Comment: Did you figure out the problem? Have you tried ith `except: -pushes` on the new repo to see if it's a repo issue?

Answer (score 2):

The below also works without using `except`

```
   only:
     - schedules
```