# gitlab-ci running only 1 line per week

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have gitlab-ci.yml file and it 's running everyday. But I want to run only 2 lines (bash script) weekly. Is it possible ? Or i should create another yml file ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example yaml?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a [pipeline schedule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) to run your pipeline weekly.

Related: [Gitlab CI - Run pipeline ONLY when triggered by CRON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519524/gitlab-ci-run-pipeline-only-when-triggered-by-cron)